# How to put web scraped numbers into a data frame that adds to the data frame when auto refreshed

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to create a data frame that updates each time my script is run. I want one column to have the number and the other to have the date that it was recorded. Here is what I have so far.

```
# Packages
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(taskscheduleR)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Read in data
team_trees <- read_html("https://teamtrees.org/")

# Number of Trees
count <- team_trees %>% 
  html_nodes("#totalTrees") %>%
  html_attr("data-count")

total_trees <- count %>%
  as.numeric()
# Columns for data frame
day <- Sys.Date()

data <- data.frame(total_trees, day)
data
```

How can I have this data frame update each time I run the script instead of replace the data frame?

Comment: Where have you considered *saving* the data? Options: csv, json, feather, database, redis/nosql, etc. If you aren't looking for permanent (i.e., new R session means fresh start), then perhaps `if (exists("dat")) { #augment; } else { #create; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is what EugeneChong suggested, saving to disk. If you aren't looking for that type of persistence, though:

```r
# ...
if (!exists("data")) data <- NULL
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(total_trees, day))
```

This is not the *cleanest* way to approach things (any failure in the `rbind`ing of data may leave all of `data` in a bad state), but since you aren't saving to a file, I'm assuming the need for persistence is different.

Ultimately, a more resilient method would use a *file* (csv, json, feather) or *network store* (SQL, redis).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you to write data to disk every time?

```
library(readr)

old_data <- read_csv("file/path/data.csv")

new_data <- old_data %>% 
  rbind(data.frame(total_trees, day))

write_csv(new_data, "file/path/data.csv")
```